# Bug using specific keyboard with UITextView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uitextview

I started up an Xcode project using the 'single view' application template and added two lines to the template-created ViewController class in viewDidLoad:

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.view.bounds, 10, 10)];
[self.view addSubview:textView];
```

In the simulator, I have enabled the "Chinese - simplified" 'Stroke' keyboard.

When I use the UITextView, switch to this keyboard, and touch the <kbd>^_^</kbd> key, the console presents the following errors:

```
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextDrawLinearGradient: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextDrawLinearGradient: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
```

Is this a bug? Should I worry about it?

Comment: Are you interacting with Core Graphics outside of drawRect:?

Comment: No - I've done nothing other than add those two lines of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have reproduced the bug in the iOS 6.0 simulator and on my iPhone 4S running iOS 6.0.1, but it doesn't happen in the iOS 5.0 simulator.  It's a bug in iOS 6.  You should open a bug report on it at http://bugreport.apple.com.

That said, it doesn't seem to be particularly harmful, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks. Two lines of code today and two questions. Two good answers though at least.

Comment: Unfortunately this may be connected to a more serious bug. Start typing with the Chinese Pinyin keyboard and suggestions pop up. Now press the power button to turn the screen off - the app crashes. This is new to iOS 6, and also affects users of Japanese input.

Answer (score 0):

it also happened in the iOS 7.0.3 simulator when i enabled 'Chinese - simplified' keyboard.

but disappeared in the iOS 7.1 simulator and iOS 8 simulator.